# Setting an state with an array variable cannot add a new property Error

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using Geolocation service and pushed coordinate changes in to an array variable but when I use set state it throws an error it says cannot add new property.

here is my code :

```js
let dataarray = []
  const startTrackingFunction = async () => {
    await Geolocation.watchPosition(
      position => {
        const crd = position.coords;

        setPosition({
          latitude: crd.latitude,
          longitude: crd.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        });
        dataarray.push(crd);
        setCoordinates(dataarray);

      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      {
        showLocationDialog: true,
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 0,
        distanceFilter: 0,
      });
    setTracking(true);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5jL6.jpg)

Comment: Hi you got a screenshot of the error ? also would be good to see the whole component including how you set the state.

Comment: Tangential, but doing a `dataArray.push` and setting it to a state value is suspicious since `push` modifies the array in-place.